# Move p-panel-menu-icon to the right

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I tried to use panel-menu in primeng.

[image]

But I want the arrow icons on the right. Like this....

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by CSS:

```css
.p-panelmenu-icon {
 order: 1; // to be the first item on right side.
}
.p-menuitem-text {
 flex-grow: 1; // to fill the whole space and push the icon to the end
}
```